# How to specify unique SNAPSHOT version in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

Currently using 2.2-SNAPSHOT as my dependency but I would like to specify a specific SNAPSHOT version (2.2-20111031.082334-13)

http://repository.excilys.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/googlecode/androidannotations/androidannotations/2.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: How to use specific version of snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086417/gradle-how-to-use-specific-version-of-snapshot)

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the unique snapshot version as you would with any other version. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile "androidannotations:androidannotations:2.2-20111031.082334-13"
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies    find $HOME/.gradle/caches/ -name "\*LIBRARY_NAME\*" -exec rm -r {} \;