# Invalid contact phone number specified for this app

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-play-publisher

I am getting this message while publishing apk using [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher)

```
{
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "androidpublisher",
      "message" : "Invalid contact phone number specified for this app.",
      "reason" : "invalidAppContactPhone"
    } ],
    "message" : "Invalid contact phone number specified for this app."
  }
```

I don't want to specify any phone number for app as it is not a mandatory field, How can I do that using `gradle-play-publisher`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in gradle-play-publisher updated build 1.1.2 :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.2'
}
```

After updating dependency and redownloading gradle dependencies following instructions [How to force gradle to redownload dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies), its fixed.

Comment: hello, i'm not using play-publisher , i manually upload using de play console web interface, but i'm having the same error. `VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_INVALID_APP_CONTACT_PHONE`

Comment: really an old post may be someone can take a look into your query

Comment: thank you but my problem is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891442/5701542

Comment: great to know that