# Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_INVALID_APP_CONTACT_PHONE

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, google-play-console

When i try to upload my aab bundle on the google play console i have to error, i dont really understand what is going on

Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_INVALID_APP_CONTACT_PHONE

i'm using ionic5

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the solution, this is due to the phone number mentionned in the "store presence" section, the phone number there is not compulsory (if you have to put it make sure to respect the format), as for me i have removed it. as on the screenshot below.

[image]