# Gradle: cascading-hive won't build due to missing jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, cascading

I'm trying to build a Cascading job that uses Hive to perform some of the transformations. The [cascading-hive](https://github.com/Cascading/cascading-hive) project seems like a great starting point. I'm running Gradle 2.6 and Java 1.8. Per the documentation, I ran the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/Cascading/cascading-hive
cd cascading-hive
gradle install
```

Unfortunately, this returned an error. A `jar` was missing from my local maven repo:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testCompile'.
> Could not find hadoop-common-tests.jar (org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/awoolford/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar
```

I searched for this `jar` on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) and it was not there.

Can you see what needs to happen in order to build cascading-hive?

**Update**

I had a quick look in the jars provided by Cloudera, found their version of this `jar` (e.g. `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.4.4-tests.jar`), and copied it to `/Users/awoolford/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar`. `gradle install` now executes successfully, though this doesn't seem like a good general solution.

Comment: Looks like a typo, the artifact is [`hadoop-common-test`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common-test)

Comment: While using cloudera, I would suggest using their versions of jars. I recently faced issues with CDH 5.5.1 version jars not working correctly with Apache jars. I changed my pom / gradle script to pull the cloudera version of hadoop and hive (hadoop: 2.6.0-cdh5.5.1 and hive: 1.1.0-cdh5.5.1) from cloudera repo.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop does not seem to be correctly downloaded in the local repo. I cannot pinpoint exactly what the exact problem in your case is. See [How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies) for suggestions on how to purge.

PS.
The jar is available in the maven central repository. See
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.hadoop%7Chadoop-common%7C2.6.0%7Cjar