# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy, gradle

I have a 1.1.7 spring-boot app using Gradle 1.10 & jdk1.8.  I use Groovy/Spock for testing It has two dependencies - jars build with Apache Maven 3.1.1 and jdk 1.8.  I build the jars and them copy them into the /lib directory.  Then I try and build with "gradle clean build.

Here is part of my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'

project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.1.7.RELEASE'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/libs"
        }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE")
  testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
}

  testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spock-core'
    exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-beans'
    exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-test'
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
}

   testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Regardless of building in from command line or IntelliJ I get the following error:

```
Executing org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler@5474aad4 in compiler daemon.
Exception executing org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler@5474aad4 in compiler daemon: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/David/projects/.../controller/AboutControllerTest.groovy' sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.
:compileTestGroovy FAILED
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:103)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/David/projects/.../src/test/groovy/.../controller/AboutControllerTest.groovy' sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:152)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonServer.execute(CompilerDaemonServer.java:53)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        ... 8 more
```

There is nothing wrong with that, or any other test, as it has not changed in months.  In fact, the problem seems to have started when I added the two jar files to the project.  However, I have not been able to find an answer to this particular error message anywhere.

Comment: Did you look at [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/language-groovy/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/compile/ApiGroovyCompiler.java)?

Comment: have you tried with a non-ancient version of gradle?

Comment: I upgraded to gradle 2.6 and I still get same error.  I also looked at ApiGroovyCompiler but didnt' see anything relevant to this.  Granted, I can't say that I totally understood everything going in there either.

Comment: Does the error go away if you temporarily remove the test class in question?

Comment: I don't get it...that test hadn't been touched in months but when I deleted it, that error no longer occurred.  What could cause that?

Comment: Because you changed something else?

Comment: funny, I should have seen that one coming :)  But no, the only change was the addition of two jar in /lib.  Anyway....I don't know who to give the answer to tim_yates or Dave Newton.  I feel both answers were helpful.

Answer (score 26):

I had this `BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '...'` issue today and upgrading gradle (as mentioned in a comment) didn't work. `gradle clean` was not working either.

What worked for me was cleaning the gradle cache:

`rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/`

and project gradle directory

`rm -rf $PROJECT/.gradle/caches/ && rm -rf $PROJECT/build/`

Related [How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies/13567793#13567793)

Comment: I use maven in my project, so doing `mvn clean` did the job

Answer (score 16):

I'm seeing the same error only when I use the Java 11 JVM:

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11 (Oracle Corporation 11+28)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64
```

The error goes away when I drop back to Java 1.8 (I changed JAVA_HOME):

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64
```

Comment: Can you specify the steps to go back to Java 1.8

Comment: On the Mac I simply changed the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point at the still-installed 1.8 JDK. I've moved on to new client since then and don't have that Mac anymore so I can't really give you exact step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 16):

My issue was that I used Java 16 and Gradle 6.5. But Gradle 6.5 does not support Java 16. I needed to upgrade to 7.0. I did this by changing `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` in this line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip
```

Comment: Or you can also downgrade your Java version if upgrading Gradle is not an option.

Answer (score 11):

Encountered the same problem while migrating SAP hybris from version 6.6 (java 8) to 2005 (java 11). The problem was encountered while ant clean all and recipe installation.

Error:

```
hybris/bin/modules/text-field-configurator-template/textfieldconfiguratortemplateocctests/testsrc/de/hybris/platform/textfieldconfiguratortemplateocctests/controllers/ProductTextfieldConfiguratorControllerTest.groovy' null
```

**Resolution:** Solved the problem by commenting/removing below property from config/local.properties

```
build.parallel=true
```

Comment: lol how did you find out, that this property is responsible for the issue? Without you I'd still be stuck for the next few weeks.....

Comment: for the record, the file is: `.\hybris\config\local.properties`.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is cause by java version is high, or we can say gradle version is too low.

so I just use higher version Gradle. I think it's better than change JDK version to 1.8.

My config(I already have gradle 6.5, and I think maybe 6.x will satisfy):

**just change the gradle version to 6.5 in `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`**

Comment: I had to set gradle version to 7.2 to use it with the jdk 16.0.2 (inside the `gradle-wrapper.properties`)

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I upgraded my project with groovy Spock tests from JDK 8 to JDK 11.

The fix was to upgrade spock version to `1.3-groovy-2.5` and groovy version to `2.5.3` for my gradle dependencies.

In addition, in my case, I had to add implementation of jaxws and jaxb to my dependencies as they have been removed from JDK 11:

```
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.4.0-b180830.0438'
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. I had to update the version of `groovy-all` from 3.0.11 to 3.0.17. This seems to have added Java 21 support

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your Gradle version is compatible with your Java version

[Gradle compatibility](https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/compatibility.html)

I upgraded my Gradle version to the latest compatible with my Java version and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the reason was IntellijIdea variable generation.

Example:
Idea generated `List<@NotNull UUID> locationIds` instead of `List<UUID> locationIds`

Groovy compilation failed to process this `@NotNull` annotation inside generic brackets

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that build:gradle version in build.gradle and distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties are compatible

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this upgrading Java on a Grails + Groovy project and I had to do two things:

1. Upgrade Grails to a version compatible with the JDK version I'm using. Thankfully they provide a nice [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)
2. Upgrade Groovy likewise. Groovy has a [matrix for the minimum version of Java required for each version of Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/download.html#requirements), but doesn't seem to show the version of Groovy required for each version of Java.

   In my case, I was using JDK 17 and I found this buried in a GitHub issue:

   > JDK 17 requires asm 9.1 and Groovy 3.0.8 is the first version to support it.

   (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12152)