# Error:BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit '_BuildScript_' unsupported Target MODULE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, java-9

I'm trying to create a new **Java 9** project using **gradle** but right after project creation I received error from gradle:

```
Error:BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit '_BuildScript_' unsupported Target MODULE
```

Java version: 9 (build 9+178)
Gradle version: 4.1-rc-2

According to [this](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) article those java/gradle versions should be compatible.
How can I solve this problem?
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the Gradle event logs for this failure as well or/and a minimal project that can be tried out to reproduce this please.

Comment: what version of grade did you use? i used 4.1, still got the same error.

Comment: same version as you

Comment: I think 4.1 is not the release candidate version 4.1-rc-2

Comment: Something similar happened for me, here is how I fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509014/1195507

Comment: Had same error message. After too many hours - turned out to be @Deprecated annotation in front of an abstract class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have solved it by downgrading Gradle JVM to 8.
It is not perfect but keeps you going while jdk9 and gradle and intellij stabilises.

[Intellij View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NtXf.png)

Answer (score 7):

Setting the Gradle home to local Gradle distribution solved the issue in my case.

- Java version: 9+181
- Gradle version: 4.1
- Intellij version: 2017.2.2

if we set to use default Gradle wrapper, IntelliJ downloads an earlier version of Gradle. I think it is the reason for failure.

[image]

Comment: Any additional step to follow? In my case it isn't working with this configuration: jdk9+181, gradle 4.1, idea 2017.2.4, linux

Comment: I did not have any issues. since gradle is a build tool, you could try to downgrade JVM of build tool to 1.8 and give a try.

Comment: Yes, for the moment I'm doing this

Comment: Didn't work for me too. Went back to JDK8 (with Gradle 4.1) which works fine. Will wait some days

Comment: If on macOS and Gradle has been installed with Homebrew, then `brew --prefix gradle` reveals the location of where `libexec/` can be found. For me, that is `/usr/local/opt/gradle`, so I set my project's Gradle home to `/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec`. I'm sure Windows' alternative Chocolatey has a similar function to find the latest installation directory.

Answer (score 3):

Seems fixed in 2017.3

See IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 173.2941.3 Release Notes: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.3+173.2941.3+Release+Notes

See issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171520

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to have been fixed in Groovy 2.4.12 and upgrading to at least that version resolved a similar problem in https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/issues/292.

Comment: Upgrading groovy fixed the issue for me.