# Jenkins on Tomcat - Pipeline fails for no reason - bug?

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, server, jenkins-pipeline

to prove myself i've installed jenkins on windows while i use it on a tomcat server.

when i went with a "node" syntax like:

```
node{
    stage('Preparation') {
        echo 'Hello world'
    }
    stage('Build') {
        echo 'same'
    }    
    stage('Results') {
        echo 'also'   
    }
}
```

the output is the same but the tomcat server finishes with: FAILURE and the windows server finishes with SUCCESS
???

---

same problem, different output:

```
   pipeline{
       agent any
       stages{
           stage('Preparation') { 
               steps{
                   echo 'Hello world'
               }
           }
           stage('Build') {
               steps{
                   echo 'same'
               }
           }    
           stage('Results') {
               steps{
                   echo 'also'   
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

this is my pipeline script code in declarative ..
and when i build my pipeline on my windows application jenkins server the output says "successful" but the same pipeline script code on my jenkins server on tomcat says "failed".

OUTPUT TOMCAT SERVER JENKINS:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'jar:file:/C:/Users/gruslak/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy' unsupported Target MODULE
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.getElementCode(Java5.java:341)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureAnnotationFromDefinition(Java5.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureAnnotation(Java5.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AnnotationVisitor.visit(AnnotationVisitor.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitAnnotation(ExtendedVerifier.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitAnnotations(ExtendedVerifier.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitConstructorOrMethod(ExtendedVerifier.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitMethod(ExtendedVerifier.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1081)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.ExtendedVerifier.visitClass(ExtendedVerifier.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:250)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:766)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:718)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelStepLoader.getValue(ModelStepLoader.java:60)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:113)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
> Blockquote
```

Comment: Maybe incompatible gradle versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899027/errorbug-exception-in-phase-class-generation-in-source-unit-buildscript

Comment: tried that too but i dont think that is my problem, anyway, i have the same gradle version on both servers, that cant be the problem

Comment: Welcome to S.O!!! #1 I don see anything related to **tomcat** in your script. #2 Are you deployed jenkins inside tomcat ?

Comment: Looks like you're running on Java 9 or later (all the "java.base/" in your stack trace). According to this document at the time of writing: https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/, Java 9 is not supported and Java 10/11 support is experimental (see the link and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46602). Obviously this may change in future. Try Java 8 for now.

Comment: ok fine, i will try that David but how does the jenkins on windows work? it works with the same jdk

Comment: fixed it by using java 8, thanks.