# groovysh > sdk - java - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, sdkman, groovysh

Running `groovysh` I get:

```
groovysh
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/snowcrash/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/2.5.2/lib/groovy-2.5.2.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Dec 19, 2019 12:00:08 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:136)
Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' null
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:972)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:633)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:582)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:354)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:87)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:320)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:318)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:547)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:559)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:443)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:482)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:453)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$evaluate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.getPackagesAndClassesFromJigsaw(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.getPackages(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.initializePackages(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.<init>(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:250)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.<init>(Main.groovy:65)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.groovy:158)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassVisitor.visitNestMemberExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:248)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:651)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:172)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:744)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:394)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromDefaultImports(ResolveVisitor.java:522)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:392)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:355)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:762)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:770)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.transformExpression(ArgumentListExpression.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:779)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:770)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformDeclarationExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1181)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:766)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:249)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1375)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:222)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$13.call(CompilationUnit.java:691)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:968)
    ... 78 more
```

What have I done wrong?

Note: I've installed java using:

```
sdk install java 11.0.5-open

Downloading: java 11.0.5-open

In progress...

############################################################################################### 100.0%

Repackaging Java 11.0.5-open...

Done repackaging...

Installing: java 11.0.5-open
Done installing!


Setting java 11.0.5-open as default.
```

FWIW, I'm following https://sdkman.io/install

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900912/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis

Comment: To run groovy with Java 11 you should use at least Groovy version 2.5. SDKMAN! can install it for you with `sdk install groovy 2.5.13` (or just go with the most recent groovy, 3.0.6 )

Answer (score -1):

Verify if your groovy is compatible with your Java version. I had an old project with Groovy version: 1.5.7 and needed to downgrade the Java version to Java 8.