# Why my Flutter app don't run? BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I tried to figure it out, but I couldn't even find how. Please help me.

When I try to run my first flutter app this happen:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Angel\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan 
to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         3.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already tried with a physical device and the emulator. I try with "flutter clean". flutter doctor -v say all is good.

If it's helpful here is what comes out when running 'flutter run -v':

```
[ +119 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +128 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
[   +2 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --points-at 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
[ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
[        ] 2.0.3
[  +85 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +77 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +79 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +2 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +129 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +78 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +188 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +124 ms] executing: C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +82 ms] List of devices attached
           R9HN50CEZ7J            device product:a11qub model:SM_A115M device:a11q transport_id:4
[  +10 ms] C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s R9HN50CEZ7J shell getprop
[ +291 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +14 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +217 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +268 ms] Generating
C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java  
[ +129 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[  +88 ms] Initializing file store
[  +22 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[  +18 ms] complete
[  +20 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on SM A115M in debug mode...
[  +15 ms] C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names   
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata --output-dill
C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.b8ee7616\flutter_tool.23a43e65\app.dill --packages
C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\.dart_tool\package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill  
build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +51 ms] executing: C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s R9HN50CEZ7J shell -x logcat -v time -t1
[  +42 ms] <- compile package:first_app/main.dart
[ +216 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    03-31 11:34:37.956 W/fb4a.ReqContexts(10384): continueFromDirect() replaced by create()
[  +21 ms] executing: C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[ +154 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
                    Version 31.0.1-7187441
                    Installed as C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[  +53 ms] executing: C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[ +135 ms] Building APK
[  +56 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[  +15 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android\gradlew.bat.
[  +40 ms] C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +25 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android/]
C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm
-Ptarget=C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true
-Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+2941 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ +137 ms] * What went wrong:
[  +14 ms] Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file
'C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\Codigo\Flutter\first_app\android\settings.gradle'
(C:\Users\Angel\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
[  +11 ms] > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60[  +25 ms] * Try:
[   +2 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.
[  +19 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +4 ms] BUILD FAILED in 2s
[ +362 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 3.6s)
[+11837 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 17,569ms.
[   +8 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:644:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)      
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)        
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +175 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 163ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hook priority 4
[+3035 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +4 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Please, I really need help.

Comment: This seems similar to the issue from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900912/bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis

Comment: "Unsupported class file major version" is the sort of error that a java runtime gives when the classfile was compiled by a newer version of java.   If the suggestions from Razvan S' linked question don't work, try making sure all of the java installs on your machine are the latest version (there could be several in different SDKs and IDEs)

Comment: I solve it! I only change my JDK version of 16 to 11 and now work good!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a problem to than i saw your comment. My JDK version of 16 downgraded to 11 and its worked.

Comment: You are life saver, I was trying my first flutter app to make it running. And was only able to do after downgrading from 16 to 11.

Comment: This happened to me after an upgrade of Android Studio and I had to follow these steps to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue..

run `flutter doctor`
and make sure you have android studio installed
that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just update **distributionUrl** value at android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to a gradle compatible with my JDK version (19)

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

So, I use gradle 7.6 following the Compatibility Matrix from Gradle docs (https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 1):

change

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by ***downgrading my JDK version 19 to JDK 17***. Also, change the paths of both - *User Variables and System Variables*.

And Don't forget to configure the ***Project Structure*** of the Flutter Project after JDK Downgrade.
[Screenshot for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOYN4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a also face this problem but instead of downgrade JDK version just update distributionUrl and build tools version it work for me

Comment: it's works for me. But i had to use gradle version compatible with my JDK version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, downgrading the jdk version solves the problem. In may case this problem was experienced both in android studio android project and in IntelJ in spring boot project.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the gradle version of java, its work for me.

1. first check the gardle java version
   => through commond : java -version
   or
   => Go to C drive -> program files -> java (where you see the jdk file and version)
2. Second check 'Edit and System Enviroment'
   => check the path  and also check the JAVA HOME path
3. Third Go to your project
   Android -> app -> gradle/wrapper -> gradle-warpper.properties
   change the gradle version

   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/*gradle-8.5*-all.zip

check with this link
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html