# Android Studio opens the wrong file when debugging a variant

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.2

An Android app has two flavors A and B. Both have foo.java

```
src
 A
  java
   foo.java
src
 B
  java
   foo.java
```

In window Build Variants, I choose **BDebug** because I want to debug flavor **B**. I have breakpoints in foo.java of **B**. When I run the app, it breaks, but in a strange place of file foo.java of **A**.

How can I debug the java files of flavor **B**?

Comment: Found a way to switch to an alternative source in debug mode in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083672/2857033. See the last option, which explains how to configure Debugger.