# Kapt, Kotlin, Dagger2 Error while annotation processing

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm getting this gradle error after adding **com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support** dependency in a project with kotlin.

This is part of my build gradle
**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    android {
      ...
       kapt {
         generateStubs = true
       }
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    ...
       kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
       kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${daggerVersion}"
       compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
       compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${daggerVersion}"

       ...
    }
```

and here the
**gradle error** that I get

```
ApplicationComponent.java:21: error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
e: 
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    e:        ^
    e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:144)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:397)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:365)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:798)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
```

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, ApplicationModule.class, RetrofitModule.class, ActivityBuilderModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        ApplicationComponent build();
    }

    void inject(TaskApplication application);
}
```

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Did you do a clean build? Kotlin with annotation processors still has a few kinks

Comment: @DavidMedenjak didn't solve

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213765/issue-with-databinding-using-kotlin-for-android/41220138#41220138

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by using the **AndroidSupportInjectionModule** once I'm using  *android.support.v4.app.Fragment*.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, ApplicationModule.class, RetrofitModule.class, ActivityBuilderModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        ApplicationComponent build();
    }

    void inject(TaskApplication application);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try adding kapt in your app level gradle file?

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Comment: this is probably the soultion, see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213765/issue-with-databinding-using-kotlin-for-android/41220138#41220138
`generateStubs = true` is not allowed with kapt3 (`apply plugin:  'kotlin-kapt'`)