# What is generateStubs configuration in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

What is `generateStubs` for Kotlin? Here is my configuration in `build.gradle`.

I can not find it in public document here : http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

```
kapt {
  generateStubs = true
}
```

If I'm using `Java` and `Kotlin(1.2)` in my project, it is still needed to add?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**EDIT**:

> If I'm using Java and Kotlin(1.2) in my project, it is still needed to
> add

**No**, With the version **1.0.4** introduces a new experimental implementation of the annotation processing API. Now there is no need to configure this `generateStubs` in `build.gradle`.

Add the following to your `build.gradle` if you want to enable it:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

You will also have to remove the `generateStubs` config from `build.gradle`

<sup>But as your question about the Details on `generateStubs` I keep my old Post as it is.</sup>

---

---

**Use :**

Using `kapt` with: `generatestubs = true`, in order to use libraries like dagger 2 or dbflow,This will enable the compiler to generate stub classes required for **interoperability between Java and Kotlin**. Unless `generateStubs = true` is enabled, "`bootstrap`" (*A custom annotation processor, which is passed to `javac`, loads the annotation data and calls other annotation processors.*) Java code is required to reference generated sources.pulled that [from](https://medium.com/@workingkills/pushing-the-limits-of-kotlin-annotation-processing-8611027b6711)

*Note : Generated codes are always in `Java` not in `Kotlin`.*

---

[**When to Include:**](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/)

Generating stubs requires relatively much work, because all declarations must be resolved, and sometimes knowing return types requires analysis of expression (bodies of functions or property initializers after the `=` sign). So, using stubs in `kapt` slows your build down somewhat. That’s why stubs are off by default, and to enable them you need to write the following in your `build.gradle` file:

```
kapt {
  generateStubs = true
}
```

---

**How this works:**

Stubs, compiler generated intermediate classes, allows "generated" sources to be referenced from Kotlin otherwise the compiler will not be able to reference the missing sources.

Generated source is created in `"build/generated/source/kapt/main"`, as this is under "**`build`**", normally excluded from IntelliJ's project sources, this source root will be marked in the build script itself.

```
sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")]
}
```

---

**Example :**

[**Dagger2-example with Kotlin (1.1.50) annotation processor support Gradle build**](https://github.com/griffio/dagger2-kotlin)

Comment: `bootstrap Java code is required to reference generated sources` Can you please tell what this means? What is "bootstrap"

Comment: I have a question. Why we can not find it on public Kotlin website? I didn't set `generatestubs = true` this in my build.gradle. But I'm using dagger2 well.

Comment: @kimkevin,A public kotlin website is having overview of new feature (not atleast  in depth as other blogs does)a link to _when to include_ is having more detail on annotation processing with kotlin. **And yes you can use dagge2 in your project with default stub but that forces to write Dagger Application class in Java.**

Comment: @kimkevin , from this _Unless generateStubs = true is enabled, "bootstrap" (A custom annotation processor, which is passed to javac, loads the annotation data and calls other annotation processors.) Java code is required to reference generated source_ I've tried to show the initial version limitations.

Comment: @Dipalis. I got it. I was curious of the posts which have `generateStubs = true` but I can not find any information in public Kotlin website. If I'm setting `generateStubs = true` in my project, do you know where generated stubs are?

Comment: I thought stubs are classes which have only method definition such as Interface.

Comment: @kimkevin, Hope my answer clears that. `Stubs, compiler generated intermediate classes, allows "generated" sources to be referenced from Kotlin otherwise the compiler will not be able to reference the missing sources.`

Comment: @Dipalis. I see. It's the last question! the latest version of Kotlin always created stubs? I checked classes from `generated/source/kapt` folder with `generateStubs = true` and without it. but generated classes are the same.

Comment: You are referencing a two-year-old blog post. This behaviour has changed since then, making your answer very misleading. Also, don't forget to reference all sources. For instance, you used definitions from [here](https://medium.com/@workingkills/pushing-the-limits-of-kotlin-annotation-processing-8611027b6711) without giving any credit to the author.

Comment: Stubs are generated automatically at a presence of an annotation processor(kapt dependency in your build script) since kapt3. You don't need to include `generateStubs = true` as part of your configuration given that `kotlin-kapt` plugin is used since kotlin 1.1 

[This answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220138/4879701) gives you a perspective on a difference in behavior....


 I had this written out as my answer - I recommend adding this information to your answer, as it will help avoid confusion when people are reading this. Does not have to be verbatim.

Comment: @Be_Negative, Updated answer to clarify the confusion.

Comment: @Dipalis. Thank you. "until and unless you run into problem with the default KAPT annotation processing implementation." this is not true, that is why I removed this from your answer. Overall, this is a good summary, well done.