# Android Studio Gradle Issue with 27.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

The following error occurs when I update the `build.gradle` file.
I use the build version as `27.0.2` and compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'` is among some of the dependancies that I require. Does anyone know what might be the cause of the issue and the solution?

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2.
>
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2.
>   Required by:
>       project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.2.6 > com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0 > com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2.
>   Could not parse POM https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/27.0.2/support-compat-27.0.2.pom

Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: It's probably because of different versions of build and Gradle. try to use the same version and let me know then.

Comment: Maybe you have a bad version of the file https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/27.0.2/support-compat-27.0.2.pom cached locally. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies

Comment: @TanvirDurlove They are already of the same version.

Comment: Thanks @Henry. It was some issue with the cache. Cleared it and it is working now.