# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.pipeline()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using the High Level Rest client from java. Specific version is 6.6.1 against an ES v6.6.1

I'm getting the following error when I try to do a BulkRequest which are all IndexRequests

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.pipeline()Ljava/lang/String;

Happy to file an issue, but was wondering if someone might know what's up in case it's a non issue.

Below is the code I'm using.  Would appreciate if anyone knows what this error is.

I'm definitely using lib 6.6.1

```
compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.6.1'
```

Thanks

```
BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "changeme"));

RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("asus.local", 9200))
    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  String[] split = line.split(",");
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(split[0]);
  Map< String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap< String, Object>();
  jsonMap.put("valuedate", date);
  jsonMap.put("value", Double.valueOf(split[1]));
  IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("my_index", "doc", String.valueOf(row))
      .source(jsonMap);
  request.add(indexRequest);
}

System.out.println("starting bulk call");
BulkResponse bulkResponse = client.bulk(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
System.out.println("DONE");
```

Comment: Looks like a discrepancy in versions of elasticsearch used to compile/build project and used to run it

Comment: I thought that might be it, so I downloaded ES 6.6.1 before posting.  I'm defo on ES 6.6.1 and here is my gradle dependency:                                             compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.6.1'

Comment: @JavaGuy look at my answer. You need to upgrade the Core library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
public String pipeline() {
    return globalPipeline;
}
```

method has been added on version `6.6` of the `Elasticsearch Server` module ([GitHub file - 6.6 branch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6.6/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkRequest.java)).

Be sure all the `Elastic Search` modules share the same version.
As you wrote the `Rest Client` is `6.6.1`, I suspect the `Server` one is older than that (`< 6.6`).

You need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or for Gradle

```
implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.6.1'
```

Comment: I was using compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.6.1' . I'll try to add the elasticsearch lib you mentioned thx

Comment: @JavaGuy that is **another module**. The one I posted is the **Core** one. And look for duplicates inside your "dependencies" block.

Comment: yes understood thx.  I'm adding both the rest high level client and the core module, correct?

Comment: @JavaGuy yes, exactly.

Comment: that's it thx.  dang - not happy since i wasted a bunch of time on it.  it would be reasonable to assume that high rest client 6.6.1 would depend on core 6.6.1 would it not?  Other products of ELK stack are all in sync version wise (ES, Kibana, LogStash etc).  Thanks for your help

Comment: @JavaGuy I understand you're a bit angry. And yes, your assumption is correct. I think you're introducing an older version of the Core module with a transitive dependency, which is unknown to you. Try to run the Dependencies task (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html) and you'll see everything

Comment: Not angry just mildly annoyed. I hear you about transitive dependencies but I literally had no other dependencies related to elastic.  sorry this didn't come out nicely . dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
  implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
  implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.6.1'
  implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.6.1'
}

Comment: before your help, i was just declaring the rest-high-level-client dependency only.  running dependencies does indeed show something using 6.4.3 .                                
 +--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.6.1
|    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.6.1 -> 6.4.3
|    |    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:6.4.3
|    |    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:6.4.3
|    |    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:6.4.3
|    |    |    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:6.4.3

Comment: @JavaGuy post the full output in the question, I'm curious to read it

Comment: SO won't let me edit the question since its already answered.  but you can look at here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j769pmhjk18ciso/dependencies.txt?dl=0    Also, here is my build.gradle (there were nothing else making reference to elastic libs other than high rest client)   https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9v8vj205juvdmr/build.gradle?dl=0

Comment: @JavaGuy I suspect this is related to caching. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies At work I usually use the "./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies" solution

Comment: @JavaGuy you can also check the SHA or MD5 of the Rest module POM file http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/6.6.1/ If it is different there is something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I solved this problem use these code.