# Spring Boot & Elastic client - NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions.ignoreThrottled()Z

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch

We created a `Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE` app with an `ElasticSearch 7.3.0` client.

When trying to run the Elastic client we get the following error for this line:

`SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);`

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions.ignoreThrottled()Z] with root cause 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.support.IndicesOptions.ignoreThrottled()Z
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters$Params.withIndicesOptions(RequestConverters.java:966)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.addSearchRequestParams(RequestConverters.java:417)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RequestConverters.search(RequestConverters.java:404)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$search$2(RestHighLevelClient.java:932)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1450)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1424)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1394)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:930)
```

We are using these dependencies:

```
 <properties>
    <spring-boot-version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
    <elasticsearch.version>7.0.0</elasticsearch.version>
</properties>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

We found [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-elasticsearch-action-index-indexrequest-ifseqno-j/176881/4) that caused us to add the `elasticsearch.version` property, but it didn't help.

We also run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see if there is a conjunction of Elastic dependencies, but it seems that only the Elastic Client has Elastic related jar.

**UPDATE**

Following [this post](https://blog.csdn.net/chengyuqiang/article/details/95981764) we tried to downgrade the Elastic client version to `7.1.1`  but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933246/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-elasticsearch-action-bulk-bulkrequest-pipeline), we discovered that the `Elastic` server has a 6.5.4 version.

Changing the dependency to

`<elasticsearch.version>6.5.4</elasticsearch.version>`

Or

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Solved the issue.