# Runing the emulator makes my whole computer crash

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Android promted me to upgrade to 3.5 today so I have. Even since I've been having issues with the AVD and running my code on the emulator.

I've posted about my previous issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945304/how-to-solve-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/57945529?noredirect=1#comment102304679_57945529)

After those solutions still didn't allow me to run the app (different errors) I've decided to just uninstal and reinstall Android studio.

Now, every time I try to run it my whole computer crashes.

It starts with this screen popping (sorry for the terrible photo, had to be quick). It says emulator warning: crash service did not start.

[image]

And then this:

[image]

What am I supposed to do? Already completely uninstalled Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know exactly what the problem was but it seemed to be solved. As I mentioned, when I've unistalled and reinstalled before the problem persisted. Even if I've uninstalled all the devices from the avd and created new ones.

This time I've done the same but didn't just install a new device, but did it with a different version (Oreo 2 instead of 26). I'm not sure why but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new emulator whose settings reduce the size of the ram and memory.