# Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0

Tags: java, android-studio, ads

I am unable to download the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
it is giving the error unable to resolve(screenshot added below)

[this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLHJB.png)

[this the build.gradle code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFzYc.png)

I have google play services installed in the sdk tools too

Please help me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Maybe you have some weird cache problems. Try with

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:*"
```

It will suggest you newest version it can get.

If it's really a cache's problem, try out this: [How can I force gradle to redownload dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies)