# Gradle refresh snapshot dependencies does not work

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, nexus, snapshot

The Stackoverflow contains some questions regarding this issue but unfortunately, nothing works for me. For example, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies)

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'net.linguica.maven-settings' version '0.5'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
        showStandardStreams true
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

mavenSettings {
    userSettingsFileName project.getProperty('settingsXml')
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}


// This configuration is necessary for publishing spring boot jar
configurations {
    [apiElements, runtimeElements].each {
        it.outgoing.artifacts.removeIf { it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(jar) }
        it.outgoing.artifact(bootJar)
    }
}

group 'com.something.company'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven {
        name 'nexus.aliter.com'
        url 'https://nexus.aliter.com/repository/cloud-maven/'
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'nexus.aliter.com'
            if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url 'https://nexus.repo.com/repository/maven-snapshots/'
            } else {
                url 'https://nexus.repo.com/repository/maven-releases/'
            }
        }
    }
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.aliter.csp', name: 'security-lib', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation group: 'com.aliter.csp', name: 'adapter-lib', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I tried this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

and I tried keyword **changing: true**, I tried **gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies** and nothing works for me. The gradle shows me that cannot find the snapshot dependencies.

We build the project through Jenkins, so in the matter of automation, it is necessary to not delete .gradle/cache every time. I am 100% percent sure that snapshot dependencies are available in the nexus repository.

**Gradle version: 6.6.1**

Comment: gradle can not FIND or can not REFRESH the dependencies?

Comment: Did you try running the build with `--info` switch? If so, can you add more information about the issue Gradle reports with the dependencies?

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, problem was that the nexus repository missed this maven-metadata.xml

[image]