# Gradle Not Syncing-Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

When Gradle tries to sync this error comes up:

```
class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @5e3a8624)
class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @5e3a8624)

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if more code is required then please let me know.

**Gradle(Module)**

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todoit"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}



dependencies {
    //ROOM
    def roomVersion = "2.4.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    // Navigation Component
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the plugins section should look like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

also, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565082/how-can-i-force-gradle-to-redownload-dependencies)