# Gradle: How to use specific version of snapshot?

Tags: android, gradle, graphhopper

I'm using SNAPSHOT version of graphhopper library.

Is there posibility to use older version of snapshot?
 I tried:

```
 compile(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper', version: '0.6-20151126.110118-54') {  

    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
}
```

As repository I use: `maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/" }`

I've tried also this repository:

```
maven {url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"}
```

but it also cannot be found.

```
Could not find com.graphhopper:graphhopper:0.6-20151126.110118-54.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.jar
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.pom
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.jar
     file:/D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.pom
     file:/D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.jar
     file:/D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.pom
     file:/D:/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/graphhopper/graphhopper/0.6-20151126.110118-54/graphhopper-0.6-20151126.110118-54.jar
```

I have tried also using local path to the gradle cache (after deleting newest snapshot dirs and leaving version I want to use) but no success. If it's impossible, is there any way to stop downloading new SNAPSNOT versions?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this link: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2784 Should have been fixed in April. Which Gradle version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but nothing changed,  I updated to Gradle 1.3.1 version and get: Failed to resolve: com.graphhopper:graphhopper:0.6-20151203.190126-58

Comment: Yes, the fix has been released in version 2.4-rc-1.

Comment: I thought android gradle plugin version. After changing Gradle version by modifying gradle-wrapper.properties file to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip everything is WORKING nice :-) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in Gradle 2.4 by GRADLE-2784, see the gradle 2.4 [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/release-notes.html#depending-on-a-particular-maven-snapshot-version).

NB: you shouldn't include the word SNAPSHOT in the artifact version, eg:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.company:my-lib:1.0.0-20150102.010203-20"
}
```